# Simplify function in Sage

Tags: sagemath

In Sage,

```
simplify(x/(x^2 + x))
```

gives

```
x/(x^2 + x)
```

I would instead expect to get

```
1/(x + 1)
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Try: $ratsimp(x/(x^2 + x))$, see: http://maxima-online.org/help/index/ratsimp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this:

```
sage: expr = x/(x^2 + x)
sage: expr.simplify_full()
1/(x + 1)
```